8 minutes past 10 Train
This is a foreign movie from the 1990's. It's called something like "8 minute past 10 train".
Fellow wants a job as an art curator but has a rival going for the same job. He kidnaps him while jogging by spraying mace and keeps him in a cellar at his girlfriend's grandfather's farm till he gets the job. He releases him without the victim knowing who and why he was kidnapped and left blinded in one eye.
Months later their paths cross and thru their partners they all become close friends. But of course the fellow who was kidnapped has no idea his new best friend was his capturer. But then things happen that reveal his friend was his kidnapper!!!

You're looking for the Dutch movie De trein van zes uur tien (AKA The 18:10 Train) from 1999.

Onno Staling has been unemployed for a while. Now his dream job finally is available: conservator at the famous Rijksmuseum in Amsterdam. There's only one obstacle, Alex Bickers is also applying for the job. To ensure he will get the job, Otto kidnaps Alex, a terrifying experience for the victim. Alex never found out who was responsible and the police thought he made it up. But when three years later Otto must select an assistant conservator, Alex is one of the candidates.

Here's the kidnapped Alex:

